# Making Angular $http optional, in a JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Is there a way to create a framework-agnostic library, but that could make use of Angular's $http service? I think the idea would be to use something else (like jQuery) if another framework is used? I am ok with having jQuery as a dependency.

I would like to create a JavaScript library that is multi-purpose, so it could be used in different frameworks. The library needs to make HTTP calls. I do like using Angular, but to make the library framework-agnostic, does that mean omitting $http altogether?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means.  It means hand-rolling all of your own ajax calls or finding another library to fiil the gap.

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: write your own (it's not **that** huge of a task) or use a micro library that has already done it. [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) looks suitable - to give you an  idea.

Comment: David, I can still dream. :)

Comment: Charlie, the problem is making a network call in a general-purpose library, but providing the ability for Angular-specific users to hook into network call events (like reporting on error responses) and other Angular goodies. Another way to look at is, is I made a service library all in Angular, with all of Angular's bells and whistles, but now I want to make it framework-agnostic.

Comment: Scniro, I agree, this isn't that huge of a task, but design decisions have consequences, so that is the reason for posting the question to get feedback.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, no - you can't rip out Angular's `$http` service and use it as a standalone.  You could, however, write your own library that mimics the syntax of the `$http` service.

Angular's `$http` is a high level object that wraps around its `$q` service.  Angular's `$q` service is itself a very similar reproduction of [Kris Kowal's Q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

If you want a lightweight Angular style `$http` object, you can simply write a wrapper around Kris Kowal's `Q`.

Comment: The danger of writing my own library is that I own the code and any issues that might come up for other developers, based on how I did the implementation; but, I do see your point, too, that $http is pieced together in angular and includes other dependencies; so, it would be very difficult. I wonder if my library simply needs to "know" which framework is used, it could "build" a service that replies accordingly? I could have two interfaces, so the developer could explicitly pick which one. myLib.ngHttp() vs myLib.ajax().

Comment: @BiagioArobba I don't think testing which framework is used is such a good idea.  For one thing, a project can have multiple frameworks.  What if a project uses both jQuery / Angular - do you use the native Angular `$http` object or your own `http` library?  Best choice would just be to build your own library and bring it onto a page when you need it.  If you're afraid of managing dependencies, you could always use something like [Bower](http://www.bower.io)